# C calculate difference between two time strokes?

Tags: c

I am trying to learn structs and functions and to make it funnier I have an assignment that asks me to create a program that scans two timestamps and calculates the difference between them.

I am already worried how the code will look like when calculating timestamps at midnight...

Anyway, I will use a function **calculateTimeToDiff()** to calculate the difference between the timestamps. The function will have two parameters, the first timestamp and the second timestamp. It will return the difference between the two tiemstamps.

**Problem 1**

I am really curious about why I can't scan values with two colons as separator:

`scanf("%d::%d::%d", &time.hours, &time.minutes, &time.seconds);`

I must type it like this (which is the proper way to type it):

`scanf("%d:%d:%d", &time.hours, &time.minutes, &time.seconds);`

**This is how I have planned to make the program, but I am sure you will rage on me and say that I should not do it like this because blabla. As I am barely understanding structs and functions, please explain how I should do like I am five:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculateTimeDiff(int time1, int time2)
{
    int difference = time1 - time2;

    return difference;
}

int main(void)
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds; 
    } Time;

    Time firstTime;
    Time secondTime;

    printf("Time #1: ");
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &firstTime.hours, &firstTime.minutes, &firstTime.seconds);

    printf("Time #2: ");
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &secondTime.hours, &secondTime.minutes, &secondTime.seconds);

    // I understand that it will not work to separate the variables with a comma, but I am kind of stuck here
    int firstFullTime   =   firstTime.hours, firstTime.minutes, firstTime.seconds;
    int secondFullTime  =   secondTime.hours, secondTime.minutes, secondTime.seconds;

    calculateTimeDiff(firstFullTime, secondFullTime);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it shouldn't even work with single `:` as well

Comment: Why not? I have used comma as separator houndreds of time when playing with coordinates. For example if the user want to inputs `2,2` as coordinates. You want to input coordinates with a comma as separator...

Comment: You **can** use "%d:%d:%d" OK. Remember to check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure you did get the three inputs you expected.  Also, there are 60 seconds in a minute and 60 minutes in an hour, so you need to do some multiplication and addition to convert hh:mm:ss into a single integer number of seconds which is what your `calculateTimeDiff` expects as input.  Using a comma operator evaluates and then ignores the LHS (left-hand side) of the operator and the expression evaluates to the RHS of the operator, so your assignment is the same as `int firstFullTime = firstTime.seconds;`.

Comment: @user2971623 wow didnt knew abt this so you were inputting value like `2:3` and want to work it on `2::3` as well then it works for me check heere-> http://i42.tinypic.com/2zgdnvr.png

Comment: You say: _I am really curious about why I can't scan values with two colons as separator: `scanf("%d::%d::%d", &time.hours, &time.minutes, &time.seconds);`_ to which the response is: If you type, for example `23::39::57`, your `scanf()` will be happy with your input, and will tell you so by returning the value 3. If you type something without two adjacent colons separating the numbers (e.g. `23:39:57`), `scanf()` will indicate that it is unhappy by returning a value other than 3 (1 for the second example input). You should always check that your input function succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a different approach:

1. For both time-stamps use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html) to read them into a "string" each.
2. Use [`strptime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) to convert the "string"s into `struct tm`s.
3. Use [`mktime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html) to create `time_t`s from the `struct tm`s.
4. Then finally use [`difftime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/difftime.3.html) to calculate the difference in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

> scanf reads data from stdin and stores them according to the parameter
>   format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments

There is not point placing any seperators (like ':'). It would be suitable if you would want to print it using printf function.

I fixed calculateTimeDiff function. You need to pass Time object here and it must return Time object if you want to check exact difference between timestamps.

Code below has been removed, it's not necessary at all after function calculateTimeDiff modification (and obviously, that code was wrong).

```
int firstFullTime   =   firstTime.hours, firstTime.minutes, firstTime.seconds;
int secondFullTime  =   secondTime.hours, secondTime.minutes, secondTime.seconds;
```

Why calculateTimeDiff returns Time? You need to know exact time difference between this two timestamps, right? Using Time object you can check exact difference (hours, minutes, seconds). I have no idea how to accomplish it using single integer.

Nevertheless code won't work properly, in case of e.g. 10 seconds (`time2`) minus 30 seconds (`time1`) result will be -20 seconds. If you want to make your own structure you have to take in account such cases. alk showed us tm structs which you could use if you want.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int hours;
  int minutes;
  int seconds; 
} Time;

Time calculateTimeDiff(Time time1, Time time2)
{
    Time result;
    result.hours = time2.hours - time1.hours;
    result.minutes = time2.minutes - time1.minutes;
    result.seconds = time2.seconds - time1.seconds;

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{

    Time firstTime;
    Time secondTime;

    printf("Time #1: ");
    scanf_s("%d\:\:%d\:\:%d", &firstTime.hours, &firstTime.minutes, &firstTime.seconds);

    printf("Time #2: ");
    scanf_s("%d\:\:%d\:\:%d", &secondTime.hours, &secondTime.minutes, &secondTime.seconds);

    Time result = calculateTimeDiff(firstTime, secondTime);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: althought its clear bt still plz add what you have fixed and why

Comment: Of course I want the input to be XX:XX:XX. I don't want the user to only type XX XX XX as input. I can't understand why you don't want the user to use the : as separator. And I don't feel like you answered my question about why I can't use two colons as separator.

Comment: It works to put anything `:` `.` `,` as separator. I have done it many times and I want the user to type **XX:XX:XX**, not **XX [ENTER] XX [ENTER] XX [ENTER]** or anything like that.

Comment: Suppose the user enters 1:00:00 (or 1 00 00 in your format), and 0:59:59. The difference should be 0:0:1; I believe you'd calculate it as 1:-59:-59. You also need to capture the difference in the calling code and then print the returned value.

Comment: On the third line, is really **Time** necessary to type? It is being typed down at the end of the struct `} Time;`.

I am confused, why is the functions parameters `Time time1` instead of `int time1`? And why isn't the function starting with `int calculateTimediff()...`?

I understand that it has to do with **Time**. Is **Time** now an object? So the function doesn't need to know if its returning a int, double, float, etc. It only has to know that it's returning an object?

It's so hard to understand when you're typing all the code for me. I appreciate your help but I can't say I am learning

Comment: @user2971623 I fixed code, now it works like you would like it to work. Input is taken as XX::XX::XX. I cannot explain why that works but escaping ':' solved issue.

Comment: I want the input to be XX:XX:XX with only one colon. I have done that many times and you don't need to escape it when you are only using one character as separator.

Comment: I'm just trying to answer your question you stated.
"I am really curious about why I can't scan values with two colons as separator: scanf("%d::%d::%d", &time.hours, &time.minutes, &time.seconds);"

Comment: My head is spinning around and around... But the code calculates the difference in hours only, I want it to calculate the minutes and seconds too. Honestly I don't really understand the code all these new objects that are being created. I just started with structs and it's too much when I get the complete code threwn in my face.

Comment: Let's walk through code, step by step. We start in main(), we create two `Time` objects because we want to calculate difference between two timestamps. Using properly formatted `scanf` we initialize `Time` objects with real values. Next we pass `Time` objects to function. Function subtract respective `Time` object members and stores result in another `Time` object. It returns `Time` object with result. Now you can use and check difference between hours, minutes and seconds. It doesn't work very well since we could subtract e.g. 4 seconds minus 10 seconds and we would get -6 seconds.

Comment: The sequence `\:` in a C string (or character) constant should elicit a warning from the compiler; the sequence is undefined, but most compilers will treat it the same as `:`.

Answer (score 0):

An initial hack at your code might produce:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds; 
} Time;

static void err_exit(char const *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}

static int calculateTimeDiff(int time1, int time2)
{
    int difference = time1 - time2;
    return difference;
}

static void print_time(char const *pre, Time t, char const *post)
{
    printf("%s%2d:%.2d:%.2d%s", pre, t.hours, t.minutes, t.seconds, post);
}

int main(void)
{
    Time t1;
    Time t2;

    printf("Time #1: ");
    if (scanf("%d:%d:%d", &t1.hours, &t1.minutes, &t1.seconds) != 3)
        err_exit("Failed to read time value");

    printf("Time #2: ");
    if (scanf("%d:%d:%d", &t2.hours, &t2.minutes, &t2.seconds) != 3)
        err_exit("Failed to read time value");

    int s1 = (t1.hours * 60 + t1.minutes) * 60 + t1.seconds;
    int s2 = (t2.hours * 60 + t2.minutes) * 60 + t2.seconds;

    print_time("T1 = ", t1, "; ");
    print_time("T2 = ", t2, "; ");
    printf("Difference in seconds (T1-T2): %d\n", calculateTimeDiff(s1, s2));

    return 0;
}
```

An example run:

```
Time #1: 1:0:1  
Time #2: 0:59:59
T1 =  1:00:01; T2 =  0:59:59; Difference in seconds (T1-T2): 2
```

The OP riposted with:

> PLEASE! I said I was new to structs and functions, do you know I *[don't]* have a clue about what half of your code means? Don't get me wrong, I am very happy to be helped by professionals, but you have to understand that this doesn't help me at all. It only confuses me more!

The code above here is a very minor modification of your existing code. The code in the section 'Code with input validation' below is a little more complex; you can ignore it for the time being (but you should be able to understand it by the end of the week; it is *not* complex, though it is ruthless in using functions to avoid repetition).

Dissecting the code above:

1. The definition of the structure type is moved outside of `main()` so that other functions can use the type too.
2. The function `err_exit` takes a string argument (`char const *msg`) and prints it on standard error (which is the correct file stream to report error messages on), and then exits the program. The exit value 0 means success; 1 is a common 'something went wrong' exit status. You could use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` if you prefer; they are defined in `<stdlib.h>` for use with the `exit()` function. Writing this function means that I can report errors in the code using a single function call instead of having to write 3 or 4 lines of code (depending on your formatting preferences) each time.  Using functions is a labour-saving technique.  It also goes by the acronym DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself.  The keyword `static` is not critical to you — it keeps my compiler happy with the options I use to prevent me making silly mistakes. We can discuss the issue separately, later, if you want to.
3. The function `calculateTimeDiff()` is your function verbatim.  Given two integer values, it returns the difference between them.
4. The function `print_time(char const *pre, Time t, char const *post)` takes three arguments. The `const` is used to tell the compiler that this function will not try to modify the strings; you could drop the word `const` without any major ill effects. The middle argument is one of your `Time` structures, so the function gets a copy of the structure on the stack. The code then calls `printf()` to print the prefix string in `pre`, the 3 numbers in the `Time` structure (`%2d` means print either 2 digits or a space and 1 digit — to a sufficiently good approximation; `%.2d` means always print 2 digits, using a leading 0 to pad if necessary), and the suffix string in `post`.  It is a simple way of formatting a time value.
5. Turning to the `main()` function, the declarations of `t1` and `t2` are same as your `firstTime` and `secondTime`, but I refuse to write such long names.
6. The `printf()` is identical to yours.
7. The call to `scanf()` is the same as yours except for the name `t1` in place of `firstTime`.  It is wrapped up in an `if` statement to check that the read operation was sucessful.  If the user types malformed input (perhaps `1::0::0`), then `scanf()` will not return 3; it will return 1 for the example input.  If the user typed `midnight`, it would return 0. If the user indicated EOF (typing <kbd>Control-D</kbd> on Unix or <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> on Windows), then `scanf()` would return EOF.
8. If the `scanf()` is not successful, then the `err_exit()` function is called to report the problem and exit the program.
9. The next paragraph of code is essentially equivalent to the code discussed in points 6-8, working with `t2` (instead of `secondTime`).
10. The next two lines use the names `s1` and `s2` in place of your `firstFullTime` and `secondFullTime`. Each line calculates the time in seconds from the values in one of your structures.  There are 60 minutes in an hour, and 60 seconds in a minute.  `(t1.hours * 60 + t1.minutes)` gives the number of minutes represented by an *hh:mm* value. When that's multiplied by 60 and the seconds are added, the result is the number of seconds since midnight represented by the *hh:mm:ss* value that the user typed.
11. The next paragraph of code uses the function `print_time()` created above to print the values in `t1` and `t2`; it is invaluable to print the input you got so you know what the computer got. Most often it will be the same as what you think the computer got, but when there's a problem, it is important to check that you and the computer think the same.  Between them, the two calls generate output such as `T1 =  1:00:01; T2 =  0:59:59;` (where there's a space after the second semicolon). If I wanted the output spread over two lines, I could replace the `"; "` argument with `"\n"`.
12. The final line calls your function `calculateTimeDiff()` with the two integer values calculated from the two structures, and then prints the result using `printf()`.  There are two seconds between '1 hour, 1 second' and '59 minutes, 59 seconds', so the `calculateTimeDiff()` function works correctly.  The program exits by `return 0;` from `main()`, indicating that it was successful.

There really isn't anything complex in this code.  The hardest part is the `scanf()`, and you wrote that — I merely added error checking to make sure it worked.  The explanation is far harder than the code. I've studiously ignored describing possible variations on the code that are feasible but not necessary.

---

#### Code with input validation

*The OP should, for the time being, ignore the rest of this answer.*

Then you might go as far as validating some of the inputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds; 
} Time;

static int calculateTimeDiff(int time1, int time2)
{
    int difference = time1 - time2;
    return difference;
}

static inline int time_to_seconds(Time t)
{
    return (t.hours * 60 + t.minutes) * 60 + t.seconds;
}

static inline Time seconds_to_time(int s)
{
    Time t;
    t.hours = s / 3600;
    t.minutes = (s / 60) % 60;
    t.seconds = s % 60;
    return t;
}

static void print_time(char const *pre, Time t, char const *post)
{
    printf("%s%2d:%.2d:%.2d%s", pre, t.hours, t.minutes, t.seconds, post);
}

static int get_time(char const *prompt, Time *t)
{
    int rc = -1;    // Assume failure
    printf(prompt);
    if (scanf("%d:%d:%d", &t->hours, &t->minutes, &t->seconds) != 3)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read time value in format hh:mm:ss\n");
    else if (t->seconds < 0 || t->seconds > 59)
        fprintf(stderr, "Seconds value %d is not in range 0..59\n", t->seconds);
    else if (t->minutes < 0 || t->minutes > 59)
        fprintf(stderr, "Minutes value %d is not in range 0..59\n", t->minutes);
    else if (t->hours < 0 || t->hours > 24)
        fprintf(stderr, "Hours value %d is not in range 0..24\n", t->hours);
    else if (t->hours == 24 && (t->seconds != 0 || t->minutes != 0))
        fprintf(stderr, "Maximum time value is 24:00:00 (you gave %2d:%.2d:%.2d)\n",
                 t->hours, t->minutes, t->seconds);
    else
        rc = 0; // All OK

    return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
    Time t1;
    Time t2;

    if (get_time("Time #1: ", &t1) != 0 ||
        get_time("Time #2: ", &t2) != 0)
        exit(1);

    int s1 = time_to_seconds(t1);
    int s2 = time_to_seconds(t2);

    print_time("T1 = ", t1, "\n");
    print_time("T2 = ", t2, "\n");
    printf("Delta (T1-T2) = %d seconds\n", calculateTimeDiff(s1, s2));
    print_time("Delta = ", seconds_to_time(calculateTimeDiff(s1, s2)), "\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Example runs (program name `dt`):

```
$ dt
Time #1: 24:00:01
Maximum time value is 24:00:00 (you gave 24:00:01)
$ dt
Time #1: -1:0:0
Hours value -1 is not in range 0..24
$ dt
Time #1: 0:-1:0
Minutes value -1 is not in range 0..59
$ dt
Time #1: 0:-1:-1
Seconds value -1 is not in range 0..59
$ dt
Time #1: 25:00:00
Hours value 25 is not in range 0..24
$ dt
Time #1: 23:60:00
Minutes value 60 is not in range 0..59
$ dt
Time #1: 23:59:60
Seconds value 60 is not in range 0..59
$ dt
Time #1: 24:01:00
Maximum time value is 24:00:00 (you gave 24:01:00)
$ dt
Time #1: 24:00:01
Maximum time value is 24:00:00 (you gave 24:00:01)
$ dt
Time #1: 24:00:00
Time #2: 0:0:0
T1 = 24:00:00
T2 =  0:00:00
Delta (T1-T2) = 86400 seconds
Delta = 24:00:00
$
```

So far, so good:

```
$ dt
Time #1: 0:0:0
Time #2: 23:59:59
T1 =  0:00:00
T2 = 23:59:59
Delta (T1-T2) = -86399 seconds
Delta = -23:-59:-59
$
```

And suddenly we get into tricky territory.  When dealing with signed segmented numbers (such as here where the segments are hours, minutes, seconds), you need to keep the sign separate from component values.  I'm not going to fix that.

Comment: PLEASE! I said I was new to structs and functions, do you know I have a clue about what half of your code means? Don't get me wrong, I am very happy to be helped by professionals, but you have to understand that this doesn't help me at all. It only confuses me more!

Comment: The only remotely complex bit in the code is the `err_warn()` function, which, now I re-review it, is not needed so I'll replace it with `fprintf(stderr, ...)`, also removing `<stdarg.h>`.  The rest is all trivial functions using trivial structures with nothing complex at all.  I already decided not to use either a compound literal or a designated initializer in `seconds_to_time()` function, even though I wrote it that way.  The first program is all very, very straight-forward. Using functions to avoid repeating yourself is standard operating procedure when programming.